# Logged into Work Machine with Google Account - Can my employer see my Google Search History?

Tags: google-chrome, sync

Hoping someone can help me here.

I logged into my Google Calendar on my work machine and absentmindedly turned sync on. Two days later, I noticed that my browsing history from my phone had showed up on my work laptop, some of which would be NSFW. I didn't access any of these sites through the work machine or through the work network, logged out as soon as I realised and all that's left now is the local search history.

Can my employer see the synced Google search history? And even if I didn't access anything NSFW through their machine/network, would any of the search terms have been flagged?

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't you asked same question couple of days ago?

Comment: Hi Toto - no I haven't, I'm a new user, have only joined the site this morning.

Comment: It's easy enough to delete the local search history.

Comment: Thanks Harry - the local history is fine now that I have turned sync off and deleted my history on the linked devices, it's just what I had been browsing while at work. My concern is whether during that time period whether the synced history was visible to my employer or if any nsfw URLs/searches could have been flagged, despite me not accessing them from my work machine or network, only from my phone and home network.